# Error response from daemon: Get https://azure/v2/: dial tcp: lookup azure: no such host

Tags: azure, docker, dockerhub, azure-container-instances

I  am trying to pull docker image from docker hub to azure following this docs on docker https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/.

when I enter the command:

```
 docker login azure
```

I get the error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://azure/v2/: dial tcp: lookup azure: no such host
```

I am not behind any vpn or proxy. I have tried some of the solutions mentioned in other threads like adding 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.8.4 in my resolv.conf and restarting docker daemon. But those solutions did not work.

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: No, I could solve my problem with your answer. For now I stopped suing docker login azure command and instead use azure cli or portal.

Comment: The Azure CLI command also does the same thing that creates a credential of the ACR for your local docker. If it works well, then the local docker will also work well. There must be something wrong you made.

Comment: I have had the same problem: `docker login azure` fails but `az login` works well. So it is clearly not a network problem.

Comment: Same problem here on ubuntu 20.04, use `az login` instead and it works as of 16/9/2021

Answer (score 3):

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I had the same problem. I fixed it by uninstalling the docker-compose package which ubuntu provided and using the install script as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#install-the-docker-compose-cli-on-linux).
The Ubuntu package doesn't seem to have the Azure integration features built-in.

Comment: I had docker composer already installed and still go the same error.

Comment: how is docker-compose installed in your case? on which OS?

Comment: I am running docker and composer on ubuntu 20.04. 
Docekr compose version: 
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

Answer (score 2):

This indicates that you've missed one of the [prerequisites](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#prerequisites). Most likely you are trying to run this from Docker CE rather than one of the Docker Desktop installs on Mac/Windows. Alternatively, replacing the `docker` binary with [one from the `docker-compose` install](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#install-the-docker-compose-cli-on-linux) should get this to work on Linux.

Comment: I removed all the docker-ce packages, went to Docker Desktop and verified that docker was enabled for wsl. Closed and launched a new WSL terminal, and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

The possible reason is that there is a policy or multiple policies in your network that block the traffic. So you can try to use another machine to log in to Azure or check the network.

Comment: I had the same problem in ubuntu 20.04, the fact that I could login with `az login` but not `docker login azure` suggestes that network is not the root cause